# Can’t figure out how to Return a value

Tags: java, return

This will probably will get down voted, so if you do down vote me, can you provided a link to where I can find this?

What am I doing wrong here? I am very new and it seems like this should work. I just don't know what I am doing wrong. This is my error

```
public class Test
{
    public static long calculate(long n)
    {   
        n = args[0];
        return n;
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        long answer;
        answer = calculate();       
    }   
}
```

Exception:

```
Test.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
                n = args[0];
                    ^
  symbol:   variable args
  location: class Test
Test.java:13: error: method calculate in class Test cannot be applied to given types;
                answer = calculate() ;
                         ^
  required: long
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
2 errors
```

Comment: args is defined in main() and can only be used there

Comment: Multiple issues.  1) `calculate()` expects a `long` as an argument, but you give it none.  2) `args` is defined locally to the `main` method, so is not visible anywhere else.  3) (implicit) `args` is an array of strings, not longs.  You need to convert the first `String` argument to a `long` somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` is a `String` array local to the `main` method.

So firstly it is a local variable of the `main` method and it is not visible inside the `calculate` method which explains the first error: `error: cannot find symbol`.

Secondly `calculate` expects a `long` parameter and your are trying to supply a `String`. For that you are getting `error: method calculate in class Test cannot be applied to given types;`

So pass `args[0]` to the `calculate` after converting it to `long` as a parameter.

```
public class Test
{
    public static long calculate(long n)
    {   
        return n;
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        long answer = 0L;
        try{
            answer = calculate(Long.parseLong(args[0]));
        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae){
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
            nfe.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(answer);      
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In whole class there is no instance variable defined with named **args**, variable which you are trying to use is a parameter in main method and **accessible only inside main** method.

By considering your code your doing nothing inside calculate so you can write main method as follows:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        long answer;
        answer = Long.parseLong(args[0]);       
    }
```

Both code will do same work.

Comment: Since the OP is trying to figure out how to return something from a method, it seems counter-productive to remove the method call.

Answer (score 0):

Below code can solve your issue

```
public class Test
{
    public static long calculate(String[] args)
    {
        long n = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        return n;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long answer;
        answer = calculate(args);
    }
}
```